# BroadcastReceiver from AlarmManager not getting called

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have a class that extends `IntentService`. The stuff in this class is called when my app reboots (and also on app startup). It *loads* some settings and does some stuff in the background (it's a productivity tool/utility).

This `IntentService`, when loading my, let's call it *"stuff"*, decides whether or not to add some alarms via `AlarmManager`. I have a BroadcastReceiver that receives some different parameters and does some method based on those parameters. Here is the code in which I am scheduling the alarms:

```
public void addAlarm(int id, int hourFrom, int hourTo, int minuteFrom, int minuteTo)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Enable
    Intent intent = new Intent(Controller.KEY_CONTROLLER_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(Controller.KEY_CONTROLLER_ACTION, Controller.KEY_ACTION_ENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Controller.KEY_CONTROLLER_ID, id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourFrom);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteFrom);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    int hours_24 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), hours_24, pendingIntent);

    // Cancel
    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(Controller.KEY_CONTROLLER_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(Controller.KEY_Controller_ACTION, Controller.KEY_ACTION_END);
    intent.putExtra(Controller.KEY_Controller_ID, id);
    PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            id,
            cancelIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourTo);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteTo);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), hours_24, cancelPendingIntent);
```

Here's the problem: The `BroadcastReceiver` (Controller class) only *sometimes* has its `onReceive` called. When it does, it's a few minutes delayed (no big deal; but it is a problem that many times it never gets called). The *second* alarm (*cancelIntent*) **never** gets called.

My *Controller* `BroadcastReceiver` is properly declared the manifest. I suspect it has something to do with both `Intent`s being identical (both have extras for type of action, as well as an ID).

What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, what is the more *proper* way to go about have a from-to based alarm? By this, I mean I need some method to happen at a certain time, and a different method (in the same class; Controller `BroadcastReceiver`) at an "end" time.

Comment: Follow this  link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) ,

Which says "If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled." But in your case, as you said  "The second alarm (cancelIntent) never gets called" which is your last instance.

Comment: @Chitrang I think by "_it will first be canceled_" means that the second one _will_ be canceled and _not_ the first. It doesn't say "the first will be canceled", it says "_**it**_ will first be canceled", referring to the second one you're trying to create. Does this mean I need to make a separate action for my `BroadCastReceiver`?

Comment: No sir, it is not other way. I have checked this in my application.

Comment: @Chitrang Right, so I will need to add another action for cancelling?

Comment: @Chitrang Added an answer, including the fix (and explanation), crediting your help.

Comment: I also just realized, perhaps the most obvious, biggest fail in this entire question, is that: After I make _cancelIntent_, I call `intent.setExtra` instead of `cancelIntent.setExtra`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my manifest to take multiple action (**real** actions, rather than pseudo-actions that I was doing via `addExtra`).

```
<receiver android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Controller">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Controller.START"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Controller.END" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then, when I add the alarms with the `Intent`, I make sure to call `setAction`, specifying the String action. In the `onReceive` of the `BroadcastReceiver` I call `getAction()` (returns a String). And voila! Both alarms fire off as intended, and I can get the type of action and perform my associated methods.

**Note:** Answered with the help of @Chitrang (via comments to the question). Pointed out that the `Intent` was getting canceled because there was already an alarm scheduled for the `IntentSender`.